# Overriding column case when mapping with NHibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I thought this would be easy to find but I am having trouble. I have a class which inherits from a class called EntityBase which has an ID field. the base class looks like this.

```
//Here is the declaration
public abstract class EntityBase<IdType>

//here is the property
private IdType _id;
public virtual IdType ID 
{
    get
    {
        return _id;
    }
    set
    {
        _id = value;
    }
}
```

This works fine for most entities but we have an entity that actually gets built from a stored proc that runs on another DB and the problem is unlike in our DB it returns "Id" not "ID" I have tried several things to override this and set ID but I keep getting the following error

NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property 'Id' in class

```
public class ListingMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<Listing>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Listing> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(x => x.ID).Column("Id");
        mapping.Id(x => x.ID).Column("Id");
    }
}
```

Here is how the entity is getting created.

```
public Listing GetListingById(Guid ListingId)
{
    IQuery query = GetSession().GetNamedQuery("GetListingById")
                        .SetParameter("ListingId", ListingId)
                        .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Listing>());

     return (query.UniqueResult<Listing>());
}
```

I know the auto mappings are getting loaded because they work for other types where we override the scheme. Hopefully that is enough information and someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with NHibernate mappings. Mappings are not involved when using named queries and result transformers.

Your problem is `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` which tries to find a property in your class for each alias returned by the query, and this is case sensitive.

You have 4 solutions:

1. If you can modify the stored procedure, change it to return the correct case. Ex: `select Id as ID`.
2. Rename the `ID` propery in `EntityBase` to `Id` and map it to the `ID` column.
3. If this is an isolated situation, drop the inheritance with EntityBase and add a property called `Id`.
4. Write your own implementation of `NHibernate.Transform.IResultTransformer`.
   Have a look at https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.cs

Comment: Yeah, in the end I got someone to modify the stored proc. I suspected that the mappings did nothing in this case however thank you for confirming that.

Comment: This resolved my problem!! In my case, the property name was as ContactCode, but I using CreateSQLQuery and was passing the alias of the my property without quotation marks. After spending quotation marks my problem was resolved. Thank you very much by this answer!!!